# Using statements no longer required?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, namespaces, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I'm wondering why I don't have to use required namespaces anymore in a .NET 7.0 application. I'm doing some tests in Blazor app and I noticed that I no longer have to include namespaces at the beginning of the file like I used to.

In that example file that I'm showing I'm using `IEnumerable` interface and `HttpClient` class. Why I don't have to use below at the beginning of the file ?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
```

If I include those anyway, then the IDE shows them as unnecessary namespaces that I can get rid - why? Where does C# know which namespace these interfaces/class needs?

I'm not aware of any file that would globally use these namespaces. Is there anything like that ?

The project is Blazor Server App. I'm using .NET 7.0, Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.6.4

[image]

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/implicit-usings-in-net-6

Answer (score 3):

> If I include those anyway, then the IDE shows them as unnecessary
> namespaces that I can get rid - why? Where does C# know which
> namespace these interfaces/class needs?

Well, It calls [implicit using directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#implicitusings), which means that you can use types defined in these namespaces without having to specify their fully qualified name or manually add a using directive.

Most importnatly, may or may not know since .NET 6 or C# 10 it has been introduced, When the feature is enabled, the .NET SDK adds global using directives for a set of default namespaces based on the type of project SDK.

**Default Project configuration .NET6 and higher:**

If you check the default configuration in .csproj file you can get the details as following:

[image]

**Note:** This features for new C# projects that target .NET 6 or later have ImplicitUsings set to enable by default.

If you would like to enable or disable this feature, you can do that as following:

```cs
<PropertyGroup>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Note:** If you wan to remove this property you can set it to false or disable. In addition, please [refer to this official document for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#implicitusings).